# Odd Multiplicities in Pascal's Triangle

Tags: binomial-coefficients

This is more of a knowledge-sharing post, but I would love more insight.
I was looking at Pascal's triangle and I was curious which numbers appear precisely an odd number of times. My first observations were:

1. 1 appears infinitely often, so it is not a candidate.
2. If $x$ appears an odd number of times, then $x={2n\choose n}$ for some $n$ (if not, then due to the symmetry of Pascal's triangle, $x$ would appear an even number of times).
3. The first occurrence of $x$ is $x={2n\choose n}$ (any preceding rows contain strictly smaller numbers).
4. The last occurrences of $x\ne 1$ are at $x={x\choose 1}$ and $x={x\choose x-1}$.
5. There are two diagonals that intersect at $x$. Between (and including) those two diagonals (below row $2n$) contain numbers strictly larger than $x$.

I haven't made much headway beyond this, so I turned to computation. I recognized that the diagonals of the triangle are strictly ascending (except those lines of 1s on the border, of course). This means that I can perform a binary search on each diagonal to locate an occurence of $x$. As well, symmetry means I only need to check the left- or right-side diagonals. Observation (4)  means I can start at the 2nd diagonal (the triangular numbers, 1,3,6,...), and point (5) means I only have to check up to the $n-1$ diagonal.

I wrote a Python program to test up to $398\choose199$ and I didn't find any numbers with odd multiplicity greater than three. This means, for example, that there are no integers smaller than $\approx 2.58026316\cdot10^{118}$ that appear 5 times.

---

I started off looking at the as-of-yet unproven [Singmaster's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singmaster%27s_conjecture), and my gut instinct was to look instead at the cases of odd multiplicity. **My hunch is that there are no numbers that have odd multiplicity greater than 3**.

It's a super accessible problem, so maybe I've infected a few more minds. I'm also unsure if this belongs on math.stackexchange or MO.

---

Python code:

```
# x is our candidate, starting at (2n-2) choose (n-1).
x=2
# To compute the next x, we need to multiply by (2n-1)(2n)/(n*n)
# This simplifies to 2*(2n-1)/n
for n in range(2,200):
  x*=(n+n-1)
  x+=x
  x/=n
#now we have our next candidate
#We need to search through the diagonals, we'll start at k=2, the 2nd diagonal (the triangular numbers)
#These evaluate to f(j)=(j(j-1)(j-2)...(j-k+1))/k!
#It's a strictly ascending sequence, so we can use a binary search.
  e=1   #this will be our k!
  print("%s : %s digits : %s" % (n,len(str(x)),x))
  for k in range(2,n):
    e*=k
    mn=n+1  #performing a binary search, this is the lower bound
    mx=x    #this is the upper bound
    p=x*e   #multiplication is generally faster than division, so instead of comparing y/k!==x, we'll test y==x*k!
    f=True
    while f and mn<mx:
      j=(mn+mx)>>1  #subdivide the interval into halves
      z=1   #computing j(j-1)(j-2)...(j-k+1)
      for f in range(k):
        z*=(j-f)
      f=z!=p  #set f=False if we have a match, causing the loop to exit early
      if z<p:
        mn=j+1  #set the new lower bound
      else:
        mx=j    #set the new upper bound
    if z==p:
      print("  %d  %d=>%d" % (e,j,z/e))
```

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2857223. It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking. You've already found the article on Singmaster's conjecture -- as far as I'm aware, that article correctly sums up the state of knowledge about the multiplicities of binomial coefficients -- what else would you like to know?

Comment: I have found these bounds on the solution set. Are there any other bounds that others might know to make it easier to compute or solve?

While I am aware that there are no known numbers that appear exactly 5 or more odd number of times, I haven't found my approach to computing being used. In a comment on the link you gave, they state that 10^60 is a bound, but my test was able to quickly rule out this subset of solutions up to 10^118.

Comment: Just a minor update-- I noticed that I could give a much better bound on where the number should lie in each diagonal and vastly improved computation. In 30min I was able to check all numbers up to ≈5*10^600. In the code, basically, initialize j≈2^((2n-k+.5)/k)*k, but that can be very optimized itself.